# How to use AZURE face recognition Rest API?

Tags: php, azure, curl, face-recognition

I am using Face API with curl in PHP. But I am having issue when matching images.
I am able to generate faceId's but when matching I get different results than expected. I have two images belonges to same person but API indicates that these images are different. But when using Microsoft demo to compare images I get right result.

Here is microsoft demo link:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/cognitive-services/face/#demo

Here are My images url

$img1 = "http://nexever.in/LibTravelSuperAdmin/images/temporary/1645715403_1.jpg";
$img2 = "http://nexever.in/LibTravelSuperAdmin/images/temporary/3.png";

Here is my code

```
<?php

function compare($image1, $image2)
{
    $faceid = array();
    $images = array($image1 , $image2);

$headers      = ["Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: ********* ","Content-Type:application/json" ]; 
/* Getting faceId */    
    foreach($images as $data)
    {   
        /* First step is to detect face */
        $request_url='https://nexever.cognitiveservices.azure.com/face/v1.0/detect?detectionModel=detection_03&returnFaceId=true&returnFaceLandmarks=false';        
        
        /* Image to get faceid */
    $detect = array('url' => $data); 
    $curl = curl_init(); curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $request_url); curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($detect)); curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);      
    $strResponse = curl_exec($curl);
    $curlErrno   = curl_errno($curl);
    if ($curlErrno) { $curlError = curl_error($curl);throw new Exception($curlError); }
    $http_status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); curl_close($curl);
    $strResponse = json_decode($strResponse , true);
    print_r($strResponse);
    array_push($faceid , $strResponse[0]['faceId']);        
    }       
    
// comparing by face ID     
/* Match face url */
$request_url = 'https://nexever.cognitiveservices.azure.com/face/v1.0/verify';      

/* Face ID to compare */
print_r($faceid);

$match = array("faceId1"=>$faceid[0], "faceId2"=>$faceid[1],"maxNumOfCandidatesReturned" =>10,"mode"=> "matchFace");
 

    $curl = curl_init(); curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $request_url);   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($match)); curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $strResponse = curl_exec($curl);  $curlErrno   = curl_errno($curl);
    if ($curlErrno) {$curlError = curl_error($curl); throw new Exception($curlError); }
    $http_status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($curl);
    return json_decode($strResponse, true);
    
}

$img1 = "http://nexever.in/LibTravelSuperAdmin/images/temporary/1645715403_1.jpg";
$img2 = "http://nexever.in/LibTravelSuperAdmin/images/temporary/3.png";
$ret =  compare($img1, $img2);

//print_r($ret);
if(isset($ret['isIdentical']))
{
    if($ret['isIdentical'] == 1)
    {
        echo "Same Person ";
    }
    else if($ret['isIdentical'] == 0)
    {
        echo "Different Person ";
    }
}


?>
```

I have successfully got face id but unable to match. If I try some other images of same person it matches sometimes. **The problem is result is not accurate.**

but on microsoft demo it is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pls try to use specify request param: `recognitionModel=recognition_04` when you detect faces as [official doc](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395236) recommanded:
[image]

I modified your code as below, it works for me perfectly:

```
<?php

function compare($image1, $image2)
{
    $faceid = array();
    $images = array($image1 , $image2);

    $faceAPIName = "nexever";
    $apikey = "<your api key>";

    $faceidAPIHost = "https://$faceAPIName.cognitiveservices.azure.com";
        
    foreach($images as $data)
    {   
        $detect = array('url' => $data); 
        $result = do_post("$faceidAPIHost/face/v1.0/detect?recognitionModel=recognition_04&detectionModel=detection_03",json_encode($detect),$apikey);
        array_push($faceid , $result[0]['faceId']);
    }       

    $request_url = "$faceidAPIHost/face/v1.0/verify";      

    /* Face ID to compare */
    print_r($faceid);

    $match = array("faceId1"=>$faceid[0], "faceId2"=>$faceid[1],"maxNumOfCandidatesReturned" =>10,"mode"=> "matchFace");
 
    return do_post($request_url,json_encode($match),$apikey);
    
}

function do_post($url, $params,$key) {
    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'header'  => "Content-type: application/json\r\nOcp-Apim-Subscription-Key: $key",
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'content' => $params
        )
    );
    $result = file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create($options));
    
    return json_decode($result, true);
}

$img1 = "http://nexever.in/LibTravelSuperAdmin/images/temporary/1645715403_1.jpg";
$img2 = "http://nexever.in/LibTravelSuperAdmin/images/temporary/3.png";
$ret =  compare($img1, $img2);

//print_r($ret);
if(isset($ret['isIdentical']))
{
    if($ret['isIdentical'] == 1)
    {
        echo "Same Person ";
    }
    else if($ret['isIdentical'] == 0)
    {
        echo "Different Person ";
    }
}

?>
```

Result of your code:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for this @Stanley Gong. But I had solved this yesterday. Still thanks.

Comment: @dummyuser Glad to know that your issue has been solved. Please click on the checkmark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to fill in to accept it as an answer, so that it will help others and close this query : )